# Class '...' not found in '...' | PHP

Tags: oop, php-7, phalcon

i've already looked up several resources and i'm pretty sure i'm doing how its supposed to be done. Unless i'm really burned out and can't notice the exact error.

I'm working on a Simple REST API Project that i can build using PhalconPHP. i followed the Micro tutorial with small modifications where i separate database calls into a separate `.service.php` file under `\service` folder to lessen codes on the route implementation. i can't seem to find any reason why it throws the error below but i keep getting it:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MyAPI\App\Routes\v1\Test\Test1RouteService' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-api\app\routes\v1\test\test_1_route.php:26 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Closure->MyAPI\App\Routes\v1\Test\{closure}() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\my-api\index.php(46): Phalcon\Mvc\Micro->handle() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-api\app\routes\v1\test\test_1_route.php on line 26`

below is the files that i currently have (excluded .htaccess):

`MyAPI\app\configurations\loader.php:`

```
<?php

    #
    # Namespace Declaration
    #
    namespace MyAPI\App\Configurations;

    #
    # Use Namespaces
    #
    use Phalcon\Loader;


    $loader = new Loader();
    $loader->registerDirs(
        array(
            __DIR__ . '/app/configurations/',
            __DIR__ . '/app/models/',
            __DIR__ . '/app/routes/v1/test/',
            __DIR__ . '/app/services/v1/test/'

        )
    )->register();

?>
```

`MyAPI\app\configurations\database.php:`

```
<?php

    #
    # Namespace Declaration
    #
    namespace MyAPI\App\Configurations;

    #
    # Use Namespaces
    #
    use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault;
    use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as MySqlPDO;


    $di = new FactoryDefault();
    $di->set('db', function() {
        return new MySqlPDO(
            [
                'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'd0r3m1f4s0',
                'dbname'   => 'test_db'
            ]
        );
    });

?>
```

`MyAPI\index.php:`

```
<?php

    #
    # Namespace Declaration
    #
    namespace MyAPI;

    #
    # Required Files
    #
    require 'app/configurations/database.php';
    require 'app/configurations/loader.php';

    #
    # Use Namespaces
    #
    use Phalcon\Mvc\Micro;
    use Phalcon\Http\Response;

    #
    # Route declaration and implementation
    #
    $app = new Micro($di);

    $app->notFound(function() use ($app) {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode(404, "Not Found");
        $response->setJsonContent([
            "status"  => 404,
            "message" => "The specified route was not found, or does not exist.",
            "data"    => null
        ]);

        return $response;
    });


    #
    # API Routes
    #
    require 'app/routes/v1/test/test_1_route.php';



    $app->handle();
```

`MyAPI\app\routes\v1\test\test_1_route.php:`

```
<?php

    #
    # Namespace Declaration
    #
    namespace MyAPI\App\Routes\v1\Test;

    #
    # Required Files
    #
    require 'app/services/v1/test/test_1_route.service.php';

    #
    # Use Namespaces
    #
    use MyAPI\App\Services\v1\Test;


    $app->get('/v1/test/what_is', function() {
        echo "My API";
    });

    $app->get('/v1/test/db_version', function() {
        // echo "called db_version route.";

        $service = new Test1RouteService();

        // echo $service->GetDbVersion();
    });

?>
```

`MyAPI\app\services\v1\test\test_1_route.service.php:`

```
<?php

    #
    # Namespace Declaration
    #
    namespace MyAPI\App\Services\v1\Test;

    #
    # Use Namespaces
    #
    use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple as Resultset;
    use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault;


    class Test1RouteService 
    {
        public function GetDbVersion()
        {
            // $sqlQry = "SELECT VERSION();";

            // $conn = FactoryDefault::getDefault()->get("db");

            return "done";
        }
    }

?>
```

i know i may or may not be implementing something how it should have been, i'll get to that later. for now i want something i can start up with.

EDIT: i'm using PhalconPHP 3.4.3 and PHP 7.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems i really am just burned out. To be able to use a class under a namespace contained in another class, you actually have to specify the end of the namespace on the declaration.

i.e.:

> use App\Namespace1\**Services**;

and then

> new **Services**\ServiceClass();

my bad, really.